# FB.ui "Feed Dialog" - Dialog box does not work on a lengthy "description" property

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Javascript SDK to generate a feed dialog box for a Facebook page that's in an iFrame:

Here's the code that calls the "feed" dialog box:

```
    function clickShare(){
        /* 400 char long string used for the description property */
       var shareDescription = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla faci';

        var publish = {
            method: 'feed',
            name: 'TITLE GOES HERE',
            caption: 'CAPTION GOES HERE',
            description: shareDescription,
            link: 'link back to page',
            picture: 'image.jpg'
        };

        FB.ui(publish);               

    }
```

It seems to work fine in all browsers in Windows, the lengthy description gets visually truncated but the dialog box has a "show more" that expands to the full description.

Unfortunately, when I try to use this in any browser *on a Mac computer* the dialog box begins to show, but never displays anything in at all.  It simply hangs on an empty, white dialog box forever.

But when I truncate the string to a length of 230 characters, the dialog box begins to work on Mac browsers.

For example, I truncate the string in JS before it gets sent to FB for the dialog popup:

```
 shareDescription = shareDescription.substr(0, 230) + "...";
```

Is anyone aware of some sort of JSON character length limitation that occurs in Mac browsers with Facebook or just in general?

Thanks for your help!